# No me funciona find con condicional if

Tags: python, condiciones, find

Estoy aprendiendo a programar. entiendo que la función o el método `find` me dice en qué posición se encuentra un índice así que me piden crear una condición. Pero el programa no me ejecuta la función.

La función es pedir que el usuario ingrese una contraseña, si la contraseña tiene menos de 10 caracteres y en la sexta posición esta el índice `@`, entonces pido que imprima `contraseña valida` y sino `contraseña invalida`.

Sin embargo el programa cumpla o no la función siempre me imprime contraseña válida.

Pondré el ejemplo:

```
cont = str(input("ingrese contraseña  ")

if len(cont)<=10 and cont.find("@"):
   print("contraseña valida")
else:
    ("contraseña invalida")
```

No importa cómo lo haga, así añada o no el `@` siempre me da que es valido como si no aplicara la condición.

Otro ejemplo:

```
cont = str(input("ingrese contraseña  ")

if len(cont)<=10 and cont.find("@==6"):
   print("contraseña valida")
else:
    ("contraseña invalida")
```

Y aquí aunque no la ponga en la posición 6 o ni siquiera exista el @ tira ("contraseña valida")

Por favor indíquenme en qué estoy errando. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Usa `... and cont.find("@") >= 0:` o bien `... and '@' in cont:`. El método `find` NO devuelve un boleano, devuelve un entero que representa la posición de la primera ocurrencia del substring en la cadena. Cómo no es un boleano, no deberías usarlo SOLO dentro de un condicional. Combínalo con alguna expresión cómo `cont.find("@") >= 0` o `cont.find("@") < 0` dependiendo de lo que quieras.

Comment: hola jaime, gracias, lo intente con cont.find("@")==6, y me dio exactamente lo que necesitaba. muchisimas gracias